# IPayIssueService' does not contain a definition for 'IssueVoucher'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

In the project I'm working on it, there is the structure between `Interface` and `Class` as below:
`Business.Treasury`'s `ClassLibrary` contains:

```
// namespace Business.Treasury.FiscalTransaction.Services
internal class PayIssueService
    : FiscalTransactionIssueService<PayModel, PY_Pay_c, v_PY_Pay_c, 
        PaySubModel, TransactionDistributionModel>
    , IPayIssueService
{
}

// namespace Business.Treasury.FiscalTransaction.Services
internal class FiscalTransactionIssueService<TMasterModel, 
    TMasterEntity, TMasterVwEntity, TMajorDetailModel,
        TMinorDetailModel>
    : IssueVoucherService, IFiscalTransactionIssueService<TMasterModel>
{
}
```

`Business.Treasury.Public`'s `ClassLibrary` contains:

```
// ns: Business.Treasury.Public.FiscalTransaction.Interfaces.Services
public interface IFiscalTransactionIssueService<TMasterModel>
    : IIssueVoucherService
{
}

// ns: Business.Treasury.Public.FiscalTransaction.Interfaces.Services
public interface IPayIssueService
    : IFiscalTransactionIssueService<PayModel>
{
}
```

`Business.Accounting.Public`'s `ClassLibrary` contains:

```
// namespace Business.Accounting.Public.IssueVouchers.Services
public abstract class IssueVoucherService : IIssueVoucherService
{
  public IssueVoucherModel IssueVoucher(
    PrimaryFiltersModel filtersModel,
    IssueVoucherModel issuevoucher,
    List<IssueVoucherSubModel> details)
  {
       //implementation
  }
}

// namespace Business.Accounting.Public.IssueVouchers.Interfaces
public interface IIssueVoucherService
{
    IssueVoucherModel IssueVoucher(
        PrimaryFiltersModel filtersModel,
        IssueVoucherModel issuevoucher,
        List<IssueVoucherSubModel> details);
}
```

In addition `Business.Treasury` has references from both `Business.Accounting.Public` and `Business.Treasury.Public`. Also `Business.Treasury.Public` has a reference from `Business.Accounting.Public`. As it is clear because of inheritance, `PayIssueService` inherits the `IssueVoucher` method. The whole project uses `IOCContainer` for `DependencyInjection` Finally, in another `ClassLibrary` I'm implementing `API` and using `IPayIssueService`:

```
// namespace WebApi.Treasury.Controllers.V01.Voucher
public class PayIssueVoucherController : ApiControllerBase
{
    IPayIssueService _payIssueService;
    PayIssueVoucherController()
    {
        _payIssueService = MyResolver.Container
            .Resolve<IPayIssueService>(mvcValidationDictionary);
    }
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> InsertAsync(
        [FromBody] InsertPayIssueVoucherDto insertPayIssueVoucherDto)
    {
        //...
        var res = _payIssueService.IssueVoucher(
            new PrimaryFilterModel(),
            issueVoucherModel,
            lstIssueVoucherSubModel);
        //...
    }
}
```

When I want to call `IssueVoucher` it throws an exception: `IPayIssueService does not contain a definition for IssueVoucher`. Why does the code throw this exception when my `Class` inherits the `IssueVoucher` method?

Comment: Perhaps your reference is out of date or the project needs to be rebuilt.

Comment: @NeutralHandle Rebuilding didn't any help.

Comment: I had something like this where the library was added as a nuget package and one of the dependencies was out of date.

Comment: @NeutralHandle Unfortunately, it didn't help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw `Stack Trace` of the exception it had this message: `Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly`. In one part of my code, In `PayIssueVoucherController` I have used a method that returns a `dynamic` value:

```
private dynamic OtherParam()
{
  return new AccountingVoucherIssuanceModel
  {
            CompanyID = Common.Security.Authorization.Authorization.CurrentCompanyId,
            FiscalYearID = Common.Security.Authorization.Authorization.CurrentYearId,
            AccVchIssMergeDebitArticles = false,
            AccVchIssMergeCreditArticles = false,
  };
}
```

And I used it in `InsertAsync`:

```
 ///...
 var otherParam = OtherParam();
 var lstIssueVoucherSubModel = GetIssueSubListModel(insertPayIssueVoucherDto, otherParam);
 ///...
```

I don't know why it's related to another method in `PayIssueVoucherController`, But changing the `OtherParam`'s output type to `Class` solved my problem! If anyone knows the reason, It will help me to understand why it caused the error!